# Pages that had the app removed, cannot add it back

Tags: facebook

I've noticed that when I add my app to certain fan pages and remove it, the app can then not be added back to those pages, but can be added to pages that haven't had the app before. Is there something I can change in my "deauthorize URL" or my "canvas URL" to change this behavior?